# Add Numbers in Sequence from 1 to any number in a Table Seats which has only one field SeatNo

Tags: database, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

I need query through which i can generate new records starting from  1 and ends at any given number.

I have a table seats. in this table i have only one field seat_no. I need seat numbers from 1 to any desired number.

So please any help....

Answer (score 0):

You need to use some kind of loop for this. To do the inserts you could use a DAO recordset or else use the CurrentDb.Execute method as show below:

```vb
Public Function AddSeats(lMax as Long)
    Dim l as Long
    l = 1
    Do Until l = (lMax + 1)
        CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO TableName (seat_no) VALUES (" & l & ")", dbFailOnError
        l = l + 1
    Loop
End Function
```